# Syntax error in Python 3.4.1 in "print" statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I'm having a trouble with a syntax error in Python 3.4.1, and I don't know what it is for. I'm trying to write a program that will convert Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa. However, I'm getting a syntax error on the final quotation mark in the print statement. Anyone know what would be causing this?

```
def celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius):
    """Converts celsius into Fahrenheit"""
    (9/5) * celsius + 32
def fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit):
    """Converts fahrenheit into celsius"""
    (5/9) * (fahrenheit - 32)

celsius = 40

print ("40 degrees celsius is", celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius)
   "in Fahrenheit")
```

Comment: You may also want to _return_ a value from your functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a comma in the function call to separate the arguments:

```
print ("40 degrees celsius is", celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius),  # <= Here
   "in Fahrenheit")
```

---

P.S. Your next question is going to be why you're not getting what you want from `celsiusToFahrenheit`. That's because you don't `return` a value. Replace the last line of each function with `return (9/5) * celsius + 32` and `return (5/9) * (fahrenheit - 32)` respectively.

Comment: I knew that I wasn't returning a value yet, but I'm working away at it. Thanks for the tip though. EDIT: It's working! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
print ("40 degrees celsius is", celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius)
   "in Fahrenheit")
```

Add a comma between each of your items:

```
print ("40 degrees celsius is", celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius),
   "in Fahrenheit")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more readable and pythonic way of printing:

```
print ("40 degrees celsius is {0} in Fahrenheit".format(celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius)))
```